# Wordpress - Google Map sporadic display

Tags: php, wordpress, google-maps

First time post here.

We are having problems with the google map above the search results on our site and thought we'd see if anyone on this site could help out, here's the page:

http://www.thehealthcard.co.uk/?category_name=all&s=richmond

The map is used to display pointers which are local offers (addresses managed via the CMS) this was built by a third party who we cannot now get hold of (fantastic!).

The map is sporadically appearing and then disappearing upon load at different times, we cannot see a reason for this at all upon investigation, Google have claimed nothing is wrong with the map and the site is not using up the free quota that Google allow for map pointer loads.

It just works sometimes and then doesn't at other times.

We have been left scratching our heads for over a week now, any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what causes it - http://note.io/1tvL0dN
Simple JavaScript error. 
Can not solve it quickly, but can you have a look at lines 44-53 in `custom.js` file. Try to increase the timeout in line 52.

Comment: Hi Alex

You're answer definitely got us on the right track!!!

The issue has now been fixed by increasing the timeout.

Thanks so much!

Chris